# Overlapping Python import statements - bad practice?

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

Frequently in my Python utilities I need to use `os.path`, and a convention I've gotten into is importing it as:

`import os.path as fs`

`fs` being my abbreviation for "file system."

I'm writing a utility now where I'll need one of the methods from `os` as well.  I tried a quick test doing this as two separate "overlapping" imports, i.e.

```
import os
import os.path as fs
[...some code referencing both os and fs...]
```

Functionally this worked fine, but I wanted to some advice on whether this "overlapping" import is bad practice.  Would it be preferable to skip my usual convention, import only `os`, and use `os.path` where needed instead of `fs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import a.b.c
```

imports `a`, `a.b`, `a.b.c` modules and defines `a` name i.e.,

```
import a
import a.b.c
```

in the end imports the same modules. For readability, you should keep the explicit `import a` if your code uses it  (removing `import a.b.c` should not affect the code that uses only `a`) i.e.:

```
import os
import os.path
```

is fine if your code uses both `os` and `os.path`. The second import is not technically necessary: `os` module is not a package (`hasattr(os, "__path__") == False`); you could use:

```
import os
fs = os.path
```

Comment: Thanks!  It was especially helpful to know that `import os.path` still gives me access to other methods from `os` (e.g. `os.listdir()`).